# render multiple iframes based on selectizeInput in shiny

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

Guessing this is quite basic for experienced r shiny users, but hoping it can help other new learners.

How can I have multiple iframes show in the below script? (i.e. if user select both a and b, the iframes appear in a stacked order on the page).

Thank you,

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("FRED Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput("checkGroup2", label = h3("Leading Indicators to compare"), 
                     choices = c("a","b"),multiple=TRUE, options = list(placeholder = 'Select graph(s)'))      
    ),

    # Show a plot of the iframe
    mainPanel(

      htmlOutput("frame")

       # fluidRow(
       #   column(3, htmlOutput("frame"))
       # ),
       # fluidRow(
       #   column(3, htmlOutput("frame"))
       # )    
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {       
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    if (input$checkGroup2 %in% "b"){

    iframeb <- tags$iframe(src="//fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-landing.php?g=irzW&width=670&height=475" , height=475, width=670)
    iframeb
    }        
    })

output$framea <- renderUI({

    if (input$checkGroup2 %in% "a"){
      iframea <- tags$iframe(src="//fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-landing.php?g=igJe&width=670&height=475", height=475, width=670)
      iframea
    }
      })      
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `conditionalPanels` for that, working example below. You may want to consider if [`checkBoxGroupInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/checkboxGroupInput.html) would be better suited for this kind of selection in your application instead of a selectizeInput, if you were not familiar with those already.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("FRED Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectizeInput("checkGroup2", label = h3("Leading Indicators to compare"), 
                     choices = c("a","b"),multiple=TRUE, options = list(placeholder = 'Select graph(s)'))

    ),

    # Show a plot of the iframe
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel('input.checkGroup2 != null && input.checkGroup2.indexOf("a")!=-1',
                       tags$iframe(src="//fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-landing.php?g=igJe&width=670&height=475", height=475, width=670)
      ),
      conditionalPanel('input.checkGroup2 != null && input.checkGroup2.indexOf("b")!=-1',
                       tags$iframe(src="//fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/graph-landing.php?g=irzW&width=670&height=475" , height=475, width=670)
      )

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```